# TestComplete scripting checkpoints and comparisons

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

SO with my limited knowledge of test Complete scripting. It seems as though one should look at the object viewer to see your windows, and use the UI features via name mapping of these objects and clicking selecting or populating their fields.

I have a question about how to do assertions using the JSscripting tests.  If i want to see if a certain window looks like a past window, what i have been doing is making a checkpoint via keyword tests at that time. I feel like i should be doing this through the api though. Is there an area that explains how to do this via code, rather then using the keyword checkpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob, the checkpoints idea is not limited to Keyword Tests. You can use checkpoints in scripts as well. When recording a script, you just create the needed Checkpoint type via the Recording toolbar (I guess you need the Region Checkpoint in your case), and you will get the needed script generated. Based on this script, you will see how checkpoints are called from a script.

As for the documentation, the ["Region Checkpoints"](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/29469/) help topic does a good job explaining basics, and giving the links to other topics to read. And the ["Creating Region Checkpoints"](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/27551/) help topic shows the procedure step by step.

I hope this helps. Let me know if there are unclear points.

Comment: That clears it up. I was alarmed that due to how similar the checkpoints looked (in the scripting area compared to the keyword test area), that maybe i should have been using something else to perform a checkpoint task when writing scripts.